# What does this bit in the GitHub URL mean?

Tags: github, repository

I made many repositories in GitHub. For some reason, in every one of them, before `/master`, "blob" is in the URL. For instance:

```
https://github.com/jmep17/website/blob/master/code.html
```

I'm trying to get rid of it. What is it? How do I rename it?

Comment: "Blob" means "binary large object". It's where git stores the contents of files. See https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/. Not sure why you care about the fact the github uses it in its URLs.

Comment: OH!! It's kind of a funny story. See, as an experiment, I made a blobfish website. Bit of fun. Called it 'blob'. I thought maybe I'd infected my entire GitHub somehow... Thanks for this. Sorry for confusion.